# fig.savefig('heatmap.png') throws error: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

So I am trying to save a visualization I'm trying to make with seaborn and matplotlib respectively, but when I save the image as a png it throws me the error in the title.
This is my code, it should be working but it may be a syntaxis mistake I'm not seeing.

```
def draw_cat_plot():
# Create DataFrame for cat plot using `pd.melt` using just the values from 'cholesterol', 'gluc', 'smoke', 'alco',
# 'active', and 'overweight'.
    df_cat = pd.melt(df, 
        id_vars=["cardio"], 
        value_vars=["cholesterol", "gluc", "smoke", "alco", "active", "overweight"])

# Group and reformat the data to split it by 'cardio'. Show the counts of each feature. You will have to rename
# one of the columns for the catplot to work correctly.
    df_cat["total"] = 1 # total column creation
    df_cat = df_cat.groupby(["cardio", "variable", "value"], as_index=False).count()

# Draw the catplot with 'sns.catplot()'
    fig = sns.catplot(x='variable', y="total", data=df_cat, hue="value", kind='bar', 
col="cardio")

# Do not modify the next two lines
    fig.savefig('catplot.png')
    return fig


draw_cat_plot()


# Draw Heat Map
def draw_heat_map():

    # Clean the data
    df_heat = df[(df['ap_lo'] <= df['ap_hi']) & 
    (df['height'] >= df['height'].quantile(0.025)) & 
    (df["height"] >= df["weight"].quantile(0.975)) & 
    (df["weight"] >= df["weight"].quantile(0.025)) &
    (df["weight"] >= df["weight"].quantile(0.975))]

    # Calculate the correlation matrix
    corr = df_heat.corr()

    # Generate a mask for the upper triangle
    mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))


    # Set up the matplotlib figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (11, 9))

    # Draw the heatmap with 'sns.heatmap()'
    fig = sns.heatmap(corr, mask = mask, vmax = 0.3, center = 0, annot = True, square 
= True, linewidths=0.5)


    # Do not modify the next two lines
    fig.savefig('heatmap.png')
    return fig

draw_heat_map()
```

Comment: `fig` is not what you think it is `heatmap` returns an `Axes`.

Comment: When you create the subplot beforehand, use `sns.heatmap(..., ax=ax)` instead of `fig = sns.heatmap(...)`.  Never use `fig = sns. ....`, as seaborn plotting functions either return an `ax` (pointing to the subplot), or some kind of grid (for ["figure-level functions"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)).